# What is the simplest method to achieve 100% CPU usage in F#?

Tags: performance, f#, cpu-usage

Sometimes I write code that I expect to be able to fully saturate the CPU.
For example, to calculate the Mandelbrot set, you might use something like this:

```
    type MandelbrotPoint =
        |Escaped of int
        |NotEscaped

    let getIterationCount maxIters (c:Complex) =
        let rec innerFunction iters (z:Complex) =
            match z.Magnitude, iters with
            |m, i when m > 2.0 -> Escaped i
            |_, i when i > maxIters -> NotEscaped
            |_ -> innerFunction (iters + 1) (z * z + c)
        innerFunction 0 c

    let getIterationCounts (topLeft:Complex) pixelWidth pixelHeight realWidth =
        let xGap = realWidth / ((pixelWidth - 1) |> float)

        [|for iY in 0 .. (pixelHeight - 1) do
                for iX in 0 .. (pixelWidth - 1) do
                    yield Complex(topLeft.Real + xGap * (float iX), topLeft.Imaginary - xGap * (float iY))
        |]
        |> Array.Parallel.map (getIterationCount 1000)
```

Naively, I would expect this to run at close to 100% until complete, but it bounces around between 25% and 60%.

I get that often calculations are constrained by how long it takes data to move into and out of the CPU cache, but that shouldn't be a problem here right? There is much data to move, its just a simple iterative calculation, no?

Comment: You may want to look into this:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370575/how-can-users-enable-background-server-gc-in-a-desktop-app-without-changing-app>

Comment: I tried running the code and I get similar results to what you described if them resolution is low, eg. 1280 by 1280, but if I beef up the resolution to 12800 by 1280, then I achieve 99% cpu utilization.

Answer (score 1):

On my 4-core 8-thread CPU the below naive snippet does pretty close to 100% CPU saturation by FSI process:

```
let consume (x: int) =
    while true do
        let  _ = x*x
        ()

[|0..7|] |> Array.Parallel.iter consume
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, mine too. So can we conclude that the bottleneck in my above code relates to memory operations after all?

Comment: I'm not an expert in bare CPU details. Nevertheless, my line of thinking moved from the opposite. Very simplistically, ignoring the factors of managed code and OS - if we short circuit all CPUs on some simplest recurring activity it would probably lead to CPU saturation. And it looks like it does, indeed.

Comment: The problem may be due to non-concurrent garbage collection.